# Can't compile any c/ c++ program, linker problem

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

It's my second post here, i have a huge problem which prevents me to study so i have to fix it as soon as it's possible !

My gcc was working fine and i had to work on FairThreads (in C). I downloaded the following archive :

[Fair Threads](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/rp/FairThreads/FTC/)

As you can see, in /src there's a makeFile, i replaced the second line which was :

```
LIB_DIR     = ../lib
```

by
`LIB_DIR     =  /usr/bin/ld`

and i compiled the makeFile by the command "make"

And now, i cannot compile any c/c++ program anymore. Even a hello world program.

I got the following error message on the terminal for every compiling attempt :

```
/usr/bin/ld: 2: /usr/bin/ld: Syntax error: newline unexpected
collect2: error: ld returned 2 exit status
```

I have found on the net this solution but it doesn't work for me :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove binutils    
sudo apt-get install binutils
```

I also tried to reinstall gcc, when executing :

```
sudo apt-get purge gcc
```

i got :

```
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
  linux-firmware
  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

but when i trie a gcc --version it tells me that it is not found.

So when i execute the command to reintall it :

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

i also get :

```
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-image-5.4.0-72-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

but gcc --version tellls that it's installed.

Finally, when i trie to compile a program, i got :

```
/usr/bin/ld: 2: /usr/bin/ld: Syntax error: newline unexpected
collect2: error: ld returned 2 exit status
```

I hope that i explained well, and i'll get a solution for this :/, as a computer science student, i can't do anything without gcc :(

EDIT 1 :

When i try to remove bin/ld by executing :

```
sudo rm -fr /usr/bin/ld;sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils
```

i got :

```
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-image-5.4.0-72-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and this particular error message :

```
WARNING: no ldd around - install libc-bin
```

EDIT :

I have installed ldd by the command :

```
sudo apt-get install libc-bin
```

still no changes...

Comment: why did you change LIB_DIR (which should point to a directory containing linkable libraries) to the /usr/bin/ld binary?

Comment: Is /usr/bin/ld a directory now?   if so, delete it (and everything it contains) with `rm -rf /usr/bin/ld/`, and reinstall ld.  `apt-get reinstall binutils`.

Comment: Well, you seem to also be missing `ldd`. Try to follow the suggestion `sudo apt-get install libc-bin`.It seems you did more than what is in the original question. It's not easy to help you recover from things we don't know about. Hope reinstalling `libc-bin` works.

Comment: i installed it but no changes...

Comment: @cas it was a mistake, i miss-followed the readme..

Answer (score 3):

You overwrote the binary `/usr/bin/ld` (although you do not say so, I assume you ran `make` as root).

You will have to remove and reinstall `/usr/bin/ld` to have a sane build environment.

If you are on a Debian derivative, `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/ld;sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils` should do it.

Comment: dpkg can behave oddly (i.e. fail to install/reinstall/remove/etc packages but with the extra "fun" of not-very-helpful or even misleading error messages) when it finds non-files (like directories) where it expects to be able to create a file.  The bogus non-file needs to be removed before the package(s) can be installed.

Comment: @cas the thing is that in this case `ld` was overwritten with another file, not a directory (I checked by running it on the actual source and pointing LIB_DIR to a file). But in general terms yes, I agree, removing the offending file/directory is a better idea. Should I update the answer?

Comment: if it was replaced with a file, your answer is a good enough for this particular question. +1 from me.   It wouldn't hurt to add a note about what to do if a directory or pipe or whatever is obstructing a package.  In general, if you know what file or file-like-thing is obstructing the reinstall, then delete it before re-installing.

Comment: Done, thanks @cas.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani i had issues when executing the command, i paste an edit on your comment